# how to deserialize objects without knowing its type or existance of its class to cast

Tags: xml, class, object, serialization, reflection

Hi everybody please do me a favor, I have many custom classes with the same structure, for example all of them have property pattern and properties of their objects are important for me to serialize,as I want to save many of these objects from many classes in many applications as log recording system so I can't gather all of classes in one solution for deserializing them.

If i have classes in my solution I can use reflection to get their properties and values and export properties in a datatable or after deserializing, cast the object to the type of that class, but my problem is how can i deserialize object and obtain "type","name" and "value" of properties of objects without having their class in my solution.

In this case when i want to deserialize  i get this error message : "Root element is missing."

Comment: You better comment what's your programming language, because not every one needs casting. For your specific problem, what's the problem with serializing class definitions and then materialize them? If your language supports a full meta-object protocol there should be no major issues.

Comment: Even if you don't have the project with the type in your solution you will still need to know the object - you will have to have a reference to the .dll that contains the type.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you can inspect a deserialized object by reflection and be sure that will be all you can have unless you have object's type somehow, I mean previously compiled in other assemblies or in the same assembly. that means you need the assembly without doubt!

But don't lose courage. By reflection you can retrieve anything you want from your objects except the things that are essential to the domain which the object's class exists within. For example you can have a deserialized instance of Product class but you can't recognize what the Product class is doing and what is it's philosophy of existence. These stuffs are put in the Product's domain in relation with Customer, Order, ProductLine, Stock and the other classes of that domain.

But again hopefully you can overcome these by defining some standard behaviors for your classes which are implemented by all of the classes in all the domains.